# How do you consume a core MVC WebApi into another Core MVC Application as of now?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to separate the presentation layer and the business logic layer with a web service.  I have read that WCF is practically dead.  I am looking for information on how to consume a webapi(mvc6 web api) into a mvc6 or a recommended way to connect the presentation layer with a web service from the business layer as of now.

I have seen older documents saying doing it one way but since its been a year since those documents have been released I am assuming there is a better way to do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use asp.net webapi to expose data from your business layer to presentation layer this can be achieved by creating project of type asp.net webapi as in the following screenshot [image]

for more information on how to achieve this you can refer to the following link which describe how to get started with MVC6 webapi 
[Creating ASP.NET Web API with MVC 6](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1219/create-aspnet-webapi-using-mvc-6)